# Incompatible Error in OpenCV 2.4.12

Tags: python, opencv, libpng

I have installed OpenCV and the detail is as follows:

> brew info opencv homebrew/science/opencv: stable 2.4.12 (bottled),
>
> HEAD Open source computer vision library http://opencv.org/
> /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12 (225 files, 36M)

Then, I run the Python to import the library of cv and get the ImportError

> ImportError: dlopen(./cv2.so, 2): Library not loaded:
> /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib   Referenced from:
> /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib
> Reason: Incompatible library version: libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib
> requires version 35.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides
> version 34.0.0

I have found some related questions and follow the suggestion to reinstall the libpng to obtain the latest version. Unfortunately, it still does not work..

Here is the details of libnpg:

> brew info libpng libpng: stable 1.6.19 (bottled), HEAD Library for
> manipulating PNG images http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html
>
> /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.19 (17 files, 1.2M)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally tackle the problem!

The "libpng16.16.dylib" in the directory: /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib is loaded when importing the cv, cv2 modules.

Even I update the version of libpng to be the latest version, new version of "libpng16.16.dylib" is still stored at: /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.19 but not /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib.

Therefore, I copy the latest version of "libpng16.16.dylib" to the directory: /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib, and it is solved!

I am not sure that it is the most appropriate solution, but at least it works.